# How to determine which JVM is attached to the running application?

Tags: tomcat, jvm, heap-dump, apm

I want to build a workflow in BMC Atrium Orchestrator which takes the heap dump of particular java process. The flow which I have to follow is :
1. Input the application name.
2. Find the JVM which is being used by the entered application.
3. Take heap hump of a process running on that JVM.

Can I get some help with step 2, i.e. how can I determine which JVM is being used by the running application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) or [jhat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) tools which are shipped along with JDK for all the things you mentioned.

Comment: jconsole and jvisualvm are GUIs, is there any command line option available for aforesaid requirements?
(I am actually trying to develop a batch process for the same)

Comment: Take a look at jhat, jcmd, jdb and others which you find under $JAVA_HOME\bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found following links which is related to your question. please refer

[Setting up Monitoring and Management Programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdhkz)

[List of running JVMs on the localhost from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200269/list-of-running-jvms-on-the-localhost)